# SQL Server replace source objects with synonyms

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, replace, synonym

I have about 100 - 150 stored procedures. I need to quickly change references to all external databases with synonyms. I have e.g. these lines of code in my procedures:

```
 select   column1, column2
 from     OtherDb.SomeSchema.SomeTable
```

or

```
 exec SOMEOTHERSERVER.OTHERDB.dbo.DOSOMETHING
```

and need to replace it with

```
 select   column1, column2
 from     dbo.FirstSynonym
```

and

```
 exec  dbo.DoSomethingSynonym
```

Manually opening all these procedures would take me considerable amount of time. Any idea how to achieve this quickly?

Thanks,
Petr

Comment: I have ViEmu for SSMS instaled, but it seems it does not support chaining commands. I also tried to record a macro but it probably records only the last "%s" command.

Comment: If you forget SQL and look at it as a simple text manipulation task, how would you do it? Is find and replace in all files using grepWin or something similar possible, or would you have to write a script using regexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bcp or sqlcmd with this query to generate a series of ALTERs

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(definition,
               'SOMEOTHERSERVER.OTHERDB.dbo.DOSOMETHING',
               'dbo.DoSomethingSynonym'
               )
           'OtherDb.SomeSchema.SomeTable',
           'dbo.FirstSynonym'
           ) + '
GO
'
FROM
    sys.sql_modules
```

You can add another REPLACE to change `CREATE PROC` to `ALTER PROC` if desired

Comment: Great! I already did the work using SMO and C#, but your solution looks easier and faster. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

- Use the Tasks->Generate Scripts feature of SSMS to generate a file with CREATE PROCEDURE statements and all your stored procedure code.
- Modify this file via Search/Replace or the ViEmu features to match your desired state.
- Delete all existing stored procedures by using the Object Explorer Details Window
- Recreate everything from the file you generated/modified.
- (please test a modification like this on a test environment first)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer gbn's solution, but I'll describe how I solved the job:

1. Iterate procedures, views and UDF using SMO (C#)
2. For each procedure, iterate all synonyms (also using SMO)
3. If procedure script contains base object names, replace them with synonyms, otherwise skip the procedure
4. return script only for procedures where changes are needed

It is also possible to directly execute the alter script from C# for each edited object, but I prefer to see the script before executing.

For obvious reason, when replacements are proceeded, synonyms have to be ordered by their base_object_name length in descending order.